# Как сравнить массив и вернуть недостающие элементы?

Tags: php, массивы, diff

Интересует вопрос, как осуществить сравнение так, что бы вернуло только те элементы, которые были в $followers_old, но в $followers_new их нет и наоборот, те которые были в $followers_new, но в $followers_old их нет.

Массивы выглядят следующим образом:

```
[113]=>
  array(4) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(8) "edyta713"
    ["profile_picture"]=>
    string(116) "https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11349347_410891465779302_1043073511_a.jpg"
    ["id"]=>
    string(10) "1468015668"
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(17) "Edyta Chęcińska"
  }
  [114]=>
  array(4) {
    ["username"]=>
    string(16) "x_inspo.quotes_x"
    ["profile_picture"]=>
    string(111) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/l/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11856807_1880099145549179_648958360_a.jpg"
    ["id"]=>
    string(10) "1964916561"
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(23) "i belive in you"
  }
```

Comment: array_diff
http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Есть еще варианты ?

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно сначала формирую промежуточный массив, а затем работаю с разницей.

```
 $n_followers_old=array_combine(array_keys(newArray($followers_old,'id')),$followers_old);
 $n_followers_new=array_combine(array_keys(newArray($followers_new,'id')),$followers_new);

 $first=array_diff_key($n_followers_old,$n_followers_new);
 $two=array_diff_key($n_followers_new,$n_followers_old);

 function newArray($array,$key)
 {
     $arr=[];
     foreach($array as $item)
     {
         $arr[$item[$key]]=$item; 
     }
     return $arr;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array_diff($followers_old, $followers_new);
$array2 = array_diff($followers_new, $followers_old);
```

Comment: проблема в том, что сравнить их нужно именно в таком виде, без индексов, ну например: в первом массиве мои подписчики за сегодня, во втором - за вчера, и вот нужно узнать кто отписался,а кто наоборот подписался...

Comment: Если `$followers_old, $followers_new` двумерные массивы как в вопросе - то `array_diff` использовать бессмысленно.

Comment: да, пробовал это, не то :( Есть решения, приятели?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [array_udiff_assoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff-assoc.php).
В вашем случае будет как-то так:

> те элементы, которые были в $followers_old, но в $followers_new их нет

```
$filtered = array_udiff_assoc($followers_old, $followers_new, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }   

    return ($a > $b) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

> те которые были в $followers_new, но в $followers_old их нет

```
$filtered = array_udiff_assoc($followers_new, $followers_old, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a === $b) {
        return 0;
    }   

    return ($a > $b) ? 1 : -1;
});
```